# Sorting Bank Accounts algorithm

Tags: java

Could anyone please help me with the code below which aims to solve this problem http://www.spoj.com/problems/SBANK/ . I am getting wrong answer although the tests show that the code is working properly as per the requirement. Please do not thick minus for my post as I am quite new to Java. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class Exercise 
{
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int pos;
String line;
int noTimes = 0;
int bTimes;
int first = 0;
int m;
// Creating an arraylist to store the result and then print it off
List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>(100000);

// List used for carrying out the checks
List<Exercise> list = new LinkedList<Exercise>();

    public String bankAccount;
    public int counter;

    // Object Template
    public Exercise (String bank)
    {
        bankAccount = bank;
        counter = 0;
    }

    // Filling the list and the arraylist
    public void fillInList() throws IOException
    {
        line = input.readLine();

        // No of test cases to follow
        noTimes = Integer.parseInt(line);

        if (noTimes <= 5)
        {

            for (int p = 1; p <= noTimes; p++)
            {
                line = input.readLine();

                // No of Bank accounts
                bTimes = Integer.parseInt(line);

                if (bTimes < 100000)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= bTimes; j++)
                    {
                        // Read the next line
                        line = input.readLine();

                        // Putting the first object in the list
                        if (first == 0)
                        {
                            Exercise element = new Exercise(line);
                            list.add(element);
                            first++;
                        }
                        // Carrying out the checks
                        compare(line);
                    }
                    // Filling the first portion of items in the arraylist
                    fill();

                    // Creating space line for the next that follows
                    System.out.print("\n");
                    first = 0;
                    // Clearing the list items in preparation for the next set
                    list.clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void compare(String lineT) throws IOException
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            Exercise object = list.get(i);

            int result = object.bankAccount.compareTo(lineT);

            // If item already present then increment counter
            if (result == 0)
            {
                object.counter++;
                break;
            }   

            // If the item is greater than the last one in the list then add it last
            else if(result < 0 && i == list.size() - 1)
            {                       
                Exercise newElement = new Exercise (lineT);
                list.add(newElement);
                newElement.counter++;
                break;
            }

            // If the input is less than item then add it right before it
            else if(result > 0)
            {
                pos = list.indexOf(object);
                Exercise newElement = new Exercise(lineT);
                list.add(pos,  newElement);
                newElement.counter++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Filling the array list
    public void fill() throws IOException
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            Exercise printObject = list.get(i);
            arr.add(printObject.bankAccount + " " + printObject.counter);
        }
        arr.add("");
    }

    // Printing the arraylist
    public void print() throws IOException
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(arr.get(i));
        }
    }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
     try
     {
        Exercise obj = new Exercise("test");
        obj.fillInList();
        obj.print();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
       return;
     }
 }  
 }
```

The results I get (copy paste from eclipse are):

```
  2
  6
  03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142
  03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141
  30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141
  30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142
  30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141
  30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142

  5
  30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0144
  30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142
  30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0145
  30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0146
  30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0143

  03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141 1
  03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142 1
  30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141 2
  30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142 2

  30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142 1
  30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0143 1
  30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0144 1
  30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0145 1
  30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0146 1
```

Comment: Can you clarify: What is 'wrong'?

Comment: "Please do not thick minus for my post as I am quite new to Java" - people won't downvote because you're new to Java. They'll downvote because you've dumped a bunch of code on us with no error message, no explanation of what you've tried to solve the problem, and no explanation of what's going wrong beyond "I am getting wrong answer although the tests show that the code is working properly".

Comment: Well, the code outputs correct results in Eclipse but when I submit it in spoj.com the judge says - wrong answer although I cannot spot an error. That's why I was wondering whether someone could help me out.

Comment: The website has example input and output. Run your code on the example input and show us what you get. (Remember to copy and paste; don't retype.)

Comment: I have added the results in my first post. Please check.

Comment: I don't think you copy-pasted the input to your program correctly. The input is supposed to have a single space at the end of each bank account. Your posted input and output seems to indicate you dropped that. (Or perhaps it was your browser's fault?)

Answer (score 0):

Two things I notice at a quick glance (did not try your code)

1) The code has to work for up to 100000 accounts, your code only works for up to 99999 accounts

2) you use a linear search to find the account number in the list, and you use the (expensive) `get()` operation on a `LinkedList` instead of a ListIterator. That way, in worst case (list is already sorted) you have an `O(n³)` performance, which I doubt works in 7 seconds for 100000 account numbers.

Try to find a sorted data structure where you can do a "binary search" in `O(log n)` time (instead of `O(n²)`) and still insert entries in constant time, and your performance will increase a lot. Or sort all the entries first and then eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

...nothing I have to say, here is the code (not good at all although):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class main
{
    static final BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(System.in));
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        int num_of_test=getIntOrExit();
        List<Map<String,Integer>> data=new ArrayList<Map<String,Integer>> (num_of_test);
        for(int i=0;i<num_of_test;++i){
            int num_of_id=getIntOrExit();
            data.add(new HashMap<String,Integer> (num_of_id));
            for(int j=0;j<num_of_id;++j){
                String line=in.readLine();
                /*to eliminate the wrong input*/
                if(line.split("\\d\\d \\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d \\d\\d\\d\\d "
                +"\\d\\d\\d\\d \\d\\d\\d\\d \\d\\d\\d\\d ").length!=0){
                    System.err.println("please follow the format:");
                    System.err.println("\"cc bbbbbbbb dddd dddd dddd dddd \"");
                    --j;
                    continue;
                }
                if(!data.get(i).containsKey(line)){
                    data.get(i).put(line,Integer.valueOf(0));
                }
                data.get(i).put(line,data.get(i).get(line)+1);
            }
            while(!in.readLine().equals("")){
                System.err.println("please input empty line");;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<num_of_test;++i){
            List<String> list=new ArrayList<String> (data.get(i).keySet());
            java.util.Collections.sort(list);
            for(String id:list){
                System.out.printf("%s %d\n",id,data.get(i).get(id));
            }
        }
    }

    public static int getIntOrExit() throws IOException{
        int output=0;
        do{
            try{
                String input=in.readLine();
                if(input.toLowerCase().equals("exit")){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                output=Integer.parseInt(input);
                break;
            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
                System.err.println("please input a number or \"exit\"");
                continue;
            }
        } while(true);
        return output;
    }
}
```